# Restricting a web service to clients running within an university

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, networking, ip-address

I created a simple web service in java. I need to restrict the access to web service to clients running within my university's network.

One approach to do this might be to get the range of ip addresses for clients running on my university network and allow access only for ip addresses within that range.
How can one go about getting this range ?

What are the other possible approaches to go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the system administrator for your university. They can tell you how their network is structured.

If you would limit access to university addresses and your university is planning to update from IPv4 to IPv6 in the near future you could be screwed.

Answer (score 1):

> How can one go about getting this range ?

You need to ask your local departmental or university systems support.  They will know where to get the information.

(You shouldn't just assume that "within the university network" means "a private IPv4 address".  Your university may already / still give out public IPv4 addresses to some users, and it may also provide networking to other people / organizations on or off campus who are not strictly part of The University.  Then there is IPv6 ... where it is likely that they will (eventually) allocate public IPs to anyone who needs one.)

If this is intended to be a long-lived web service, I would also recommend that you implement the restriction in the server's (OS-level) firewall rules rather than in the web server itself.  That will make the IP blocking more visible to the administrators, and easier for them to manage / change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally all the machines in your university should be using private IP addresses. There are basically three ranges of private IP v4 addresses as mentioned here:

```
10.0.0.0 through 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 through 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255
```

Now you have a range of IPs to block for your webservice clients.